# Function name with ampersand operator in c

Tags: c

If a function name is a pointer to itself, why is the function name with `&` operator also an address of the function? Is it not the address of pointer to the function?

```
 void f(int a);

    // ....
    void(*P)(int)=&f;
    P(2); // why(*p)(2) is also correct?
```

Comment: Because you get the address of the function. Invoking functions in assembly language is nothing but jumping to the function address and continueing from there..

Comment: @Neijwiert I think he meant: `addressof(Function) != addressof(&Function)` but the left is just sugar for the right.

Comment: @NaCl Oh I see, then I misread the question.

Comment: For op: the last declaration of your function pointer is: `int (*p)(int)` which is not the same as `void f(int)`, note the return type, ***pretty strict C code***  would not allow this kind of stuff.

Comment: @NaCl yes i maked mistake...i edited